# Java Library to Retrieve HttpServletRequest parameters

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web

I am developing an application that uses `Servlets`. I was asked not to use `Struts2 or JSF or SpringMVC` by my boss but only `Servlets and Jsps`. In my `Servlet` I will need to call `request.getParameter("parameterName")` to retrieve a parameter value.
**My question**
Is there a Java Library in existence that I can pass a `JavaBean` and `HttpServletRequest` Objects to and return a populated `JavaBean`. i.e. The `JavaBean` automatically populated with the request parameters.

Comment: What would the JavaBean empower you to do, that the `HttpServletRequest` doesn't?

Comment: @DavidWallace The `JavaBean` will contain form fields that will be sent to the backend. When a form is submitted, I want to populated this `JavaBean` by calling the API that the Library that I am looking for will provide with the `HttpServletRequest` Object.

Comment: Are you saying you're using using some kind of ORM tool which needs a bean?

Comment: @DavidWallace I want to be able to submit a form retrieve the http parameter in a servlet and call my backend service to persist it in the database. Please read my question?

Comment: @DavidWallace presumably using some sort of bean mapping framework would allow for the automatic type validation of the submitted form parameters. Combine that with JSR 303 and you have a simple way to check user input without handwriting thousands of `Integer.parseInt` type things.

Comment: @Boris, yeah I figured that might have been it.  Just checking though.  No point in providing an answer that doesn't match what the OP actually wanted.  And yes, thanks eric, I read your question.

Comment: There is a [method in Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtilsBean.html#populate(java.lang.Object,%20java.util.Map)) that does what you want.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Passing the `JavaBean` and `request.getParameterMap()` to the method in `BeanUtils`, can it do the Job? If it can, you can post it as an Answer and I will mark it so that It can help other users.

Comment: @Boris if you post that as an answer, I will upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My usual goto with any sort of JavaBean reflection stuff is [Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) and sure enough they have an appropriate method in [`BeanUtilsBean`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtilsBean.html#populate%28java.lang.Object,%20java.util.Map%29):

> `public void populate(Object bean,
>               Map<String,? extends Object> properties)
>                 throws IllegalAccessException,
>                        InvocationTargetException`
>
> Populate the JavaBeans properties of the specified bean, based on the
>   specified name/value pairs. This method uses Java reflection APIs to
>   identify corresponding "property setter" method names, and deals with
>   setter arguments of type String, boolean, int, long, float, and
>   double. In addition, array setters for these types (or the
>   corresponding primitive types) can also be identified.
>
> The particular setter method to be called for each property is
>   determined using the usual JavaBeans introspection mechanisms. Thus,
>   you may identify custom setter methods using a BeanInfo class that is
>   associated with the class of the bean itself. If no such BeanInfo
>   class is available, the standard method name conversion ("set" plus
>   the capitalized name of the property in question) is used.
>
> NOTE: It is contrary to the JavaBeans Specification to have more than
>   one setter method (with different argument signatures) for the same
>   property.
>
> WARNING - The logic of this method is customized for extracting
>   String-based request parameters from an HTTP request. It is probably
>   not what you want for general property copying with type conversion.
>   For that purpose, check out the copyProperties() method instead.

Note that it is *customized for extracting String-based request parameters from an HTTP request* so it is exactly what you want. The issue being being HTTP request parameters come in the form of a `Map<String, String[]>` to need to be unwrapped from the array.

I did a quick test to ensure it worked as expected. I noticed that the class **must** be `public` and in its own file for the introspection to work.

I create a JavaBean like so:

```
public class JavaBean {

    String userName;
    String password;
    Integer id;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

And used the following for a quick test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Map<String, String[]> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("userName", new String[]{"userA"});
    params.put("password", new String[]{"secrect"});
    params.put("id", new String[]{"10"});
    final JavaBean javaBean = new JavaBean();
    BeanUtilsBean.getInstance().populate(javaBean, params);
    System.out.println(javaBean.getUserName());
    System.out.println(javaBean.getPassword());
    System.out.println(javaBean.getId());

}
```

Output is as expected:

```
userA
secrect
10
```

I also noticed that it doesn't seem to like `int` for the numeric property - seems to expect an `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

Jive Software from Ignite Realtime has a BeanUtils class that appears to do what you want.  It is open source.  I have never used it.  It's in the OpenFire download [here](http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/index.jsp).

Comment: Please can you post a link to the Util class. Is that util open source?